# Cannot retrieve all items from large SharePoint list via Excel data connection

Tags: 2010, list, excel, list-view-threshold, data-connection

I have a large SharePoint 2010 list (~60,000 items) in which the list view threshold has been turned off.  Recently, we've encountered the problem that exporting the list to Excel only yields a subset of the total number of items.  Sometimes, refreshing the data connection will return 4,000 records to Excel.  Sometimes it will return 20,000, etc.  There doesn't appear to be any consistency in this, so my assumption is there there is some sort of network interruption happening.

Can anyone suggest some troubleshooting methods for this problem?  I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

For test purpose, can you please try exporting using the below script, which creates a csv file with the values in SharePoint List.

```
$MyWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sitename"
$MyWeb.Lists["ListName"].Items |
     ForEach-Object{
          New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                          Column1=$_["Column Name in SharePoint"]
                                          Column2=$_["Column Name in SharePoint"]                  
                                         }
     } | Export-Csv -path 'C:\FilePath\Filename.csv'
```

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/c284bca0-def8-4493-8136-3949f8b62ced/export-sharepoint-2010-list-items-into-csv-file-using-managment-shell?forum=ITCG)

Comment: Hi, Karthik.  Provided that this script retrieves all of the data, I don't see how it would be relevant since it needs to run on the server whereas exporting to Excel is client-side.